# Replacing string that have not been already replaced

Tags: php

So I have a text like this:

```
"word1 word2 word3 etc"
```

And I have an array with a set of replacment that I have to carry like this:

```
[    
     "word1 word2" => "<a href="someurl">word1 word2</a>",
     "word2"       => "<a href="someurl">word2</a>",
     "word3"       => "<a href="someurl">word3</a>" 
]
```

Basically for some of the words (or a combination of them) I have to add some tags.

I need to avoid that since "word1 word2" is already replaced like this:

```
<a href="someurl">word1 word2</a> word3 etc
```

I need to avoid that it becomes like this:

```
"<a href="someurl">word1 <a href="someurl">word2</a></a> word3 etc"
                            ^^^ another replacement inside "word1 word2"
```

How can I avoid replacemnet of smaller strings already found inside other replacement ?

### Live code using str_replace not working:

```
$array = [    
     "word1 word2" => "<a href='someurl'>word1 word2</a>",
     "word2"       => "<a href='someurl'>word2</a>",
     "word3"       => "<a href='someurl'>word3</a>" 
];

$txt = "word1 word2 word3 etc";

echo str_replace(array_keys($array),array_values($array),$txt);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85fd62e88cd0131125ca7809976694ee4c975b6b

### Correct output:

```
<a href="someurl">word1 word2</a> <a href="someurl">word3</a> etc
```

Comment: I think this can be solved by using regular expressions, have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = [    
 "word1 word2" => "<a href='someurl'>word1 word2</a>",
 "word2"       => "<a href='someurl'>word2</a>",
 "word3"       => "<a href='someurl'>word3</a>" 
];

 $txt = "word1 word2 word3 etc";

foreach ($array as $word => $replacement) {
   if (!stripos($txt, ">$word<") && !stripos($txt, ">$word") && !stripos($txt, "$word<") ){
    $txt = str_replace($word, $replacement, $txt);
   }
}
echo $txt;

// output: <a href='someurl'>word1 word2</a> <a href='someurl'>word3</a> etc
```

Basically, before you replace the word, check if it's wrapped in tags already

Comment: Yes this would be a way, but it feels like to be not so elegant

Comment: @giò I agree with you, it is probably not the most elegant solution, but it works and it is relatively easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's the best solution but you could replace the combination of words for something entirely different, then when you're done replace that back to it's original form.

Example

```
$array = [    
     "word1 word2" => "<a href='someurl'>***something***else***</a>",
     "word2"       => "<a href='someurl'>word2</a>",
     "word3"       => "<a href='someurl'>word3</a>",
];

$array2 = [    
     "***something***else***" => "word1 word2",
];

$txt = "word1 word2 word3 etc";
$txt = str_replace(array_keys($array),array_values($array),$txt);
$txt = str_replace(array_keys($array2),array_values($array2),$txt);

echo $txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe adding "space" at key of set of replacement array and do `str_replace()`. something like this maybe:

```
<?php
    //Enter your code here, enjoy!

    $array = [    
         "word1 word2 " => "<a href='someurl'>word1 word2</a>",
         "word2 "       => "<a href='someurl'>word2</a>",
         "word3 "       => "<a href='someurl'>word3</a>" 
    ];

    $txt = "word1 word2 word3 etc";

    echo str_replace(array_keys($array),array_values($array),$txt." ");
```

Comment: No can't do this because i could have some punctuation like this: word1 word2. word3